# What's the best way to internationalize a Facebook canvas app (iframe) in the post-FBML era?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

After (finally) adding some analytics to my Facebook app and realizing that English is pretty far down on the list of my users' languages, I started to look into the [official docs on internationalization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/).

However, the docs almost entirely refer to FBML and the `<fb:intl>` tag, and as of this month (June 2012), support FBML has been [entirely removed](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/06/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/).

The docs make brief mention of using the REST API to call intl.getTranslations (which is also legacy), or querying the translation FQL table (which seems like a lot of overhead for a previously simple task).

So, am I missing something obvious here? **What's the new recommended way to mark up and display translated phrases on a canvas app without using FBML?**

Comment: I have the same question/problem. Also reported this as a bug on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a Facebook recommended way, but here is how we do it :
- we read the facebook locale sent by Facebook through the signed request
- we see if we have translations for this language
- if not we serve a default language

obviously, that requires you to perform the translations yourselves rather than using the community and tools provided by Facebook, but you could write a tool to get the translations from google translate.

Hope that helps ?